# Adding user in AWS without access to IAM and billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am looking to add a user in AWS. I have a group with supportUser policy.

The thing is, he can create users and change passwords.

With supportUser policy, he is not able to view any payment information, billing or anything regarding the account.

I am looking for a policy that would only allow him to create a EC2 container, S3 storage and a database. Nothing more. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

AWS gives you options to create your own fine-grained policies or you can simply use managed policies. Managed policies provide a gentler introduction because AWS has provided curated policies for you. Managed policies are also updated periodically to incorporate new function or new services, as relevant to each specific managed policy.

See [AWS managed policies for job functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_job-functions.html) or, more generally, [AWS managed policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_cn/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#aws-managed-policies).

The simplest managed policies for your use case are probably:

- AmazonEC2FullAccess
- AmazonRDSFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess

Important note: each of these policies grants the user significant permissions over **all** EC2, RDS, and S3 resources so you may find them too permissive for your use case.

If you want more control then write your own policies. Start at [Policies and permissions in IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html). You can also copy/paste the contents of a managed policy and then edit it down to just the permissions you want, and constrained to the resources that you want (e.g. to specific, named S3 buckets).

Comment: I did that last night. Thanks anyways.